# How to write mongodb query for regex in GoLang using bson?

Tags: regex, mongodb, go, bson

I want to do wildcard search in records with firstname in mongodb using go mongodb driver.

I'm using below query to achieve it.

```
filter := bson.D{{Key: "tenantId", Value: cmd.TenantID}}
if cmd.FirstNameSearch != "" {
    filter = append(filter, bson.E{Key: "firstName",
        Value: bson.M{"$regex": primitive.Regex{Pattern: "^" + cmd.FirstNameSearch + "$", Options: "i"}}})
}
```

This is not working for me. Could you please correct me if I'm doing anything wrong.

Even in and not in are also not working.

```
if len(cmd.StatusIn) > 0 {
    filter = append(filter, bson.E{Key: "status", Value: bson.E{Key: "$in", Value: cmd.StatusIn}})
}
if len(cmd.StatusNotIn) > 0 {
    filter = append(filter, bson.E{Key: "status", Value: bson.E{Key: "$nin", Value: cmd.StatusNotIn}})
}
```

cmd.StatusIn is slice of string ([]string)

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: returning no records even there are records that criteria

Answer (score 14):

Below is an example on how to query with regex with [mongo-driver](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver) v1.0 :

```
filter := bson.D{{Key:"foo", Value:99}}
filter = append(filter, bson.E{Key:"bar", Value: bson.D{
        {"$regex", primitive.Regex{Pattern:"^ThisValue.*", Options:"i"}},
    }},
)
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), filter )
```

The example above also append a [BSON element bson.E](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#E) for a [BSON Document bson.D](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#D) filter. Similar to your example.

I would suggest to check the struct that you're decoding the result of the query, and/or whether there's a matching document(s) in the collection.

Comment: This is searching the exact value with case insensitive by not searching for part of string

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your sentence means. Could you try to elaborate ? The example snippet is only to show how to specify regex query with the driver, not to show how to use regex. You can use different regex patterns for the `Pattern` itself.

Comment: Yeah, When I gave bson.D instead of bson.M it worked for me and you rightly said I need to write different regex pattern.

Comment: What does the Options field do?

Comment: @Jack, options represent options for the regular expression. In the case above `i`, means case insensitivity to match upper and lower cases. For list of available options please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_options