# Golang Mongodb collection members starts with a string query

Tags: mongodb, go

Mongodb collection has a array type and members are string. I want to get if a member of array starts with "abc". How can I write a filter for that?

collection example:

```
{
_id:"1",
name:"",
data:["abcdfd","gfgqqdg","abcfdgsfg"]
},
{
_id:"2",
name:"",
data:["abcdfd","gfgqqdg","ghfdgsfg"]
},
{
_id:"3",
name:"",
data:["hjhfdfd","gfgqqdg","afdgsfg"]
}
```

So, find query must return first and second because the "data" has members start with "abc".

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) as shown below:

```
db.collection.find({
  "data": {
    "$regex": "/^abc*/"
  }
})
```

Also checkout: [How to write mongodb query for regex in GoLang using bson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55740288/how-to-write-mongodb-query-for-regex-in-golang-using-bson)

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB, you can match any element in array of data using the following syntax:

```
db.collection.find({ "data": "abcdfd" })
```

To find documents where any of the array values *starts a string "abc"*, you can use any of the queries:

```
db.collection.find({ "data": "^abc" })
db.collection.find({ data: { $regex: "^abc" }})
db.collection.find({ data: { $regex: /^abc/ }})
```

Where, `^` (caret) is a special character used with regular expressions; *matches the starting position of a string*.

The Golang version of the query:

```
var results []bson.M
filter := bson.D{{ "data", bson.D{{ "$regex", "^abc" }}}}
cur, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), filter)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

if err = cur.All(context.TODO(), &results); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
for _, result := range results {
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```